# Bold symbol in Matlab legend

Tags: matlab, legend

I have a plot in Matlab with the following legend:

```
h = legend('Reference','$\hat{\theta}_2 = 5\theta_2$','$\hat{\theta}_2 = 10\theta_2$');    
set(h,'Interpreter','latex')
```

Now I want to make the variables `\theta` bold faced for use in my LaTeX report.

I already tried:

```
h = legend('Reference','$\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}_2 = 5\mathbf{\theta}_2$','$\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}_2 = 10\mathbf{\theta}_2$');    
set(h,'Interpreter','latex')
```

Unfortunately this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason bold symbols are just possible with the **Tex interpreter**, but this way you can't use `\hat{...}`. So you need to decide, if you either want to use **bold symbols** or the **hat** and other Latex-only Stuff:

```
x = 1:100;
y1 = sin(x/2).^2;
y2 = -sin(x/2).^2;

f = figure(1);
p(1) = plot(x,zeros(numel(x),1)); hold on
p(2) = plot(x,y1); hold on;
p(3) = plot(x,y2); hold on;


h1 = legend(p(1:2),'Reference','\bf{\theta}_2 = 5\cdot \theta_2');    
set(h1,'Interpreter','tex','Location','NorthEast')

nh = copyobj(h1,f);

h2 = legend(p(3),'$\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}_2 = 5\cdot \mathbf{\theta}_2$');    
set(h2,'Interpreter','latex','Location','SouthWest')
```

[image]

I'm afraid there is no other in-Matlab solution. I'd recommend to just save the plot as vector graphic and post process it with Illustrator or Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen dealing with LaTeX in Matlab plots can be cumbersome. You can consider to give a try to the toolbox [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz), which will convert your figure in compilable LaTeX code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a quick and dirty solution, but for me

```
$\hat{\mbox{\textit{\textbf{h}}}}$
```

worked.